# Alter the element, if particular element not found as its descendant

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest. If element 'mfenced' does not have elements like 'munderover' or 'mfrac' as its descendant, then it needs to be changed to element 'mo'.
Find the 'text1' and 'text2' text in the xml, in these area my code unable to change to 'mo'.

Input XML:

```
    <article>
    <math>
        <mi>P</mi>
        <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--To be changed to 'mo', bcs 'mfenced' not having mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
            <mi>g</mi>
        </mfenced>
        <mfenced open="[" close="]"><!--To be retained as it is, bcs, mfenced having either mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
            <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--To be retained as it is, bcs, mfenced having either mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
                <mi>g</mi>
                <mo>=</mo>
                <munderover>
                    <mrow><mn>1</mn></mrow>
                    <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--To be changed to 'mo', bcs 'mfenced' not having mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
                        <mrow><mi>text1</mi></mrow>
                    </mfenced>
                    <mrow><mi>N</mi></mrow>
                </munderover>
            </mfenced>
            <mi>N</mi>
        </mfenced>
        <mfenced open="[" close="]"><!--To be retained as it is, bcs, mfenced having either mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
            <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--To be retained as it is, bcs, mfenced having either mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <mfenced open="(" close=")"><!--To be changed to 'mo', bcs not having mfrac or munderover as its descendant-->
                            <mi>text2</mi>
                        </mfenced>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow><mo>2</mo></mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </mfenced>
        </mfenced>
    </math>
</article>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="mfenced">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::mfrac|descendant::munderover">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="mo">
                <xsl:value-of select="@open"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:element name="mo">
                <xsl:value-of select="@close"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//comment"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Result:

```
    <article>
   <math>
      <mi>P</mi>
      <mo>(</mo>
        <mi>g</mi>
      <mo>)</mo>
      <mfenced open="[" close="]">
          <mfenced open="(" close=")">
              <mi>g</mi>
            <mo>=</mo>
            <munderover>
               <mrow>
                  <mn>1</mn>
               </mrow>
               <mo>(</mo><!--My code failing here-->
                  <mi>text1</mi>
               <mo>)</mo>
               <mrow>
                  <mi>N</mi>
               </mrow>
            </munderover>
         </mfenced>
         <mi>N</mi>
      </mfenced>
      <mfenced open="[" close="]">
         <mfenced open="(" close=")">
            <mfrac>
               <mrow>
                  <mo>(</mo><!--My code failing here-->
                      <mi>text2</mi>
                  <mo>)</mo>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                  <mo>2</mo>
               </mrow>
            </mfrac>
         </mfenced>
      </mfenced>
   </math>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. I have changed the following:

- Replaced `copy-of` with a directed `apply-templates` that in turn will select the identity template for all further nodes
- Changed the last template match to `comment()`, because you would like to catch comments, not element nodes that are called "comment", I'd say. The `//` there is not needed.

What was wrong with your approach? It did not account for *nested* `mfenced` elements, because once the template match for `mfenced` triggered, you simply copied all its content, including all potential `mfenced` elements inside it.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mfenced">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::mfrac|descendant::munderover">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <mo>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </mo>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="comment()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<article>
   <math>
      <mi>P</mi>
      <mo open="(" close=")">
         <mi>g</mi>
      </mo>
      <mfenced open="[" close="]">
         <mfenced open="(" close=")">
            <mi>g</mi>
            <mo>=</mo>
            <munderover>
               <mrow>
                  <mn>1</mn>
               </mrow>
               <mo open="(" close=")">
                  <mrow>
                     <mi>text1</mi>
                  </mrow>
               </mo>
               <mrow>
                  <mi>N</mi>
               </mrow>
            </munderover>
         </mfenced>
         <mi>N</mi>
      </mfenced>
      <mfenced open="[" close="]">
         <mfenced open="(" close=")">
            <mfrac>
               <mrow>
                  <mo open="(" close=")">
                     <mi>text2</mi>
                  </mo>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                  <mo>2</mo>
               </mrow>
            </mfrac>
         </mfenced>
      </mfenced>
   </math>
</article>
```